# Having a problem fixing the carousel selector. My target is to showcase image at the center not on the left

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, slider

Having a problem fixing the carousel selector. My target is to showcase image at the center not on the left. the slides are working properly only the showcase item has issue. [this is the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxYhA.jpg) thanks.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script>

var $ = jQuery
    
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.as-slider').each(function(){

var $this = $(this),
    currentSlide = 0,
    previousSlide = 0,
    slideNumber = $this.find('.as-side-slider .swiper-slide:not(.swiper-slide-duplicate)').length,
    barHTML = '',
    forward,
    textContainer = $this.find('.as-changing-widget')
   
for(var i=0; i<slideNumber;i++){

    barHTML += `<span class="dot"><span class="dot-number">${i+1}</span></span>`
}

$this.find('.as-bar .dot').remove()
$this.find('.as-bar').append(barHTML)
$this.find('.as-bar .dot').eq(0).addClass('active')
    
textContainer.each(function(){
    var texts = $(this).find('.elementor-widget').eq(0)
    texts.addClass('currentUp')
    $(this).css('--h', texts.height()+'px')
})

setTimeout(function(){
    $this.addClass('loaded')
    if($this.find('.as-side-slider .swiper-container-initialized, .as-side-slider .swiper-initialized').length){
        $this.find('.as-side-slider').addClass('loaded')
    }

    var init = setInterval(function(){
        if($this.find('.as-side-slider .swiper-container-initialized, .as-side-slider .swiper-initialized').length){

            $this.find('.as-side-slider').addClass('loaded')
            clearInterval(init)
        }
    },50)
}, 500)

var bgs = JSON.parse($this.attr('data-settings')).background_slideshow_gallery,
    bgHTML = '<div class="as-slider-background">'

if(bgs){
    bgs.forEach(function(background){
        bgHTML += `<img src="${background.url}"/>`
    })
}
bgHTML += '</div>'

$this.find('.as-slider-background').remove()
$this.prepend(bgHTML)

var backgrounds = $this.find('.as-slider-background img')

backgrounds.eq(0).addClass('currentForward')

setInterval(function(){
    currentSlide = $this.find('.as-side-slider .swiper-slide-active').attr('data-swiper-slide-index')
    if(previousSlide != currentSlide) {

        if( previousSlide < currentSlide ){
            forward = true
        }
        if( previousSlide > currentSlide ){
            forward = false
        }
        if( previousSlide == slideNumber - 1 && currentSlide == 0 ){
            forward = true
        }
        if( previousSlide == 0 && currentSlide == slideNumber - 1 ){
            forward = false
        }
        textContainer.each(function(){
            var texts = $(this).find('.elementor-widget')
            
            $(this).css('--h', texts.eq(currentSlide).height()+'px')
            
            texts.removeClass('prev next currentUp currentDown')
            backgrounds.removeClass('prev currentBackward currentForward')
            
            backgrounds.eq(previousSlide).addClass('prev')
            
            if(forward) {
                texts.eq(previousSlide).addClass('prev')
                texts.eq(currentSlide).addClass('currentUp')
                
                backgrounds.eq(currentSlide).addClass('currentForward')
                
            }else{
                texts.eq(previousSlide).addClass('next')
                texts.eq(currentSlide).addClass('currentDown')

                backgrounds.eq(currentSlide).addClass('currentBackward')
            }
        })
        
        $this.find('.as-bar .dot').removeClass('active')
        $this.find('.as-bar .dot').eq(currentSlide).addClass('active')
    }
    previousSlide = currentSlide
}, 500)

$this.find('.as-bar .dot').on('click', function(){
    
    var index = $(this).index()
    
    $this.find('.as-side-slider .swiper-pagination-bullet').eq(index).trigger('click')
    $this.find('.as-side-slider .swiper-container').trigger('mouseleave')
    
})
$this.find('.as-slider-left').on('click', function(){
    
    $this.find('.as-side-slider .elementor-swiper-button-prev').trigger('click')
    $this.find('.as-side-slider .elementor-swiper').trigger('mouseleave')
})
$this.find('.as-slider-right').on('click', function(){
    
    $this.find('.as-side-slider .elementor-swiper-button-next').trigger('click')
    $this.find('.as-side-slider .elementor-swiper').trigger('mouseleave')
})
$this.find('.as-slider-left a, .as-slider-right a').on('click', function(e){
    
    e.preventDefault()
})

})
})

$(window).on('resize', function(){
    
    
$('.as-slider').each(function(){
    
    var textContainer = $(this).find('.as-changing-widget')
    
    textContainer.each(function(){
        var texts = $(this).find('.elementor-widget.currentUp, .elementor-widget.currentDown')
    
        $(this).css('--h', texts.height()+'px')
    })
})
})

</script>
```

Tried to put this CSS

```
selector{
    --radius: 8px;
    --height: 320px;
    --active-height: 410px;
    --overlay: 0.75;
}
selector{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100px);
    transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
selector.loaded{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

selector .swiper-wrapper{
    height: var(--active-height);
    align-items: center;
}
selector:not(.loaded) .swiper-wrapper{
    transition-duration: 0s !important;
}
selector .swiper-slide{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    border-radius: var(--radius);
    height: var(--height);
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
selector.loaded .swiper-slide{
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
selector .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active{
    height: var(--active-height);
}
selector .swiper-slide:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgb(0,0,0);
    background: linear-gradient(20deg, rgba(0,0,0,var(--overlay)) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
selector .elementor-testimonial__footer{
    display: block;
}
selector img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: var(--radius);
}
selector .elementor-testimonial__cite{
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
selector .elementor-testimonial__name{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
selector .swiper-pagination,
selector .elementor-swiper-button{
    display: none;
}
selector .swiper-container{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px){
selector{
    --height: 180px;
    --active-height: 250px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
selector{
    --height: 80px;
    --active-height: 105px;
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: var(--container-widget-width, 300px) !important;
}
selector .elementor-testimonial__cite{
    opacity: 0;
}
}
```

but the it showcase the left item not the center item. I want it also others that are not showcased or not in the center to adjust size descending.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .elementor-testimonial__cite {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute; /* Change to absolute for centering */
    left: 50%; /* Adjust to center the element */
    transform: translateX(-50%); /* Adjust to center the element */
}

   .swiper-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto; /* Change to center the container */
        }
```

Kindly modify this CSS and conduct a test to see if it functions correctly.